# Access member variables after destructor call

Tags: c++, explicit-destructor-call

i have code like this:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    void blub () {}
};
class Test {
  public:
  Foo& foo;
  Test (Foo& f) : foo (f) {}
  void test () {
    this->~Test ();
    foo.blub ();
  }
};
```

After the explicit call to the destructor, all member variables of my `Test` class are probably inaccessible, so the call `foo.blub()` is invalid. If I store the reference in a local variable to avoid access to the member variable, is the call to `foo.blub()` guaranteed to work? Can't the compiler optimize the local variable out and access the member variable after the destructor call, making it invalid again?

```
class Foo {
  public:
    void blub () {}
};
class Test {
  public:
  Foo& foo;
  Test (Foo& f) : foo (f) {}
  void test () {
    Foo& f = foo;
    this->~Test ();
    f.blub ();
  }
};
```

Comment: The object bound to `f` is not relevant to the question. The evaluation of `f` itself, which is actually `this->f`, is invalid, since `this` is not a valid `Test` pointer after you ended the lifetime of `*this`.

Comment: `f` is _not_ `this->f`. `f` is _local_ to `test()`.

Comment: BTW: You'd better not _ever_ allocate an object of `Test` on the stack _and_ call `test()`, otherwise boom!

Comment: Indeed. My instances will be allocated via placement new on a char array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local `f` refers to an object outside of `Test` and `f` will persist as long as `test()` does, so yes it will work.